# URL Conditional Wordpress Widget Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to update a widget on a Wordpress site that links to a calendly link to be conditional.  If the visitor is on page "A" I need the link to reference "Person 1" but on all other pages I need the calendly link to reference "Person 2"

I'm a data person, and google is my go to when trying to accomplish anything in HTML or php, so please be kind. This is what I've attempted (using a PHP if else in HTML wrapper), but it's saying the "?php" is incorrect syntax:

```
<?php if ( $CurPageURL = ‘https://examplewebsite.com/our-business/womens-worth-finding-your-financial-confidence/’ ) 
{ <!-- Calendly badge widget begin -->
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: https://calendly.com/person-1', text: 'Schedule A Call', color: '#798591', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false });</script>
<!-- Calendly badge widget end --> } 
else { <!-- Calendly badge widget begin -->
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: 'https://calendly.com/person-2', text: 'Schedule A Call', color: '#798591', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false });</script>
<!-- Calendly badge widget end --> } ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like something happened to the closing tag (`<!-- Calendly badge widget end → } ?>`. The `→` character should be `-->`.

Comment: @JonEdwards--good catch, but that doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately....

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with PHP, sorry about that. :) Here's a sandbox with code that does what you want. You can change the value of $CurPageURL to test what is output (when clicking "Execute"). You'll want to remove the assignment before using it, or you'll override what $CurPageURL is set to.    http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/691f30be042010661fcf2e7442469917f5844602

Comment: @JonEdwards--thanks, that sandbox is handy!  I got some syntax issues worked out but after some in depth research to many whitepage documents it turns out Wordpress Customizable HTML widgets don't recognize php unless you pay for a business plan.  Bummer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render any html content with php, you need to use the `echo` syntax.

This should work :

```php
<?php
if ( $CurPageURL = "https://examplewebsite.com/our-business/womens-worth-finding-your-financial-confidence/" )
{
    echo "
    <!-- Calendly badge widget begin -->
    <link href=\"https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
    <script src=\"https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: https://calendly.com/person-1', text: 'Schedule A Call', color: '#798591', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false });</script>
    <!-- Calendly badge widget end -->
    ";
}
else
{
    echo "
    <!-- Calendly badge widget begin -->
    <link href=\"https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
    <script src=\"https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">Calendly.initBadgeWidget({ url: 'https://calendly.com/person-2', text: 'Schedule A Call', color: '#798591', textColor: '#ffffff', branding: false });</script>
    <!-- Calendly badge widget end -->
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: @KawaLo--thanks for the tip.  That helped solved some of my php syntax errors.